# How to play a youtube video in ember application

Tags: video, ember.js, handlebars.js

What I have tried -

Model -

```
App.Video = DS.Model.extend({
   url: DS.attr('string'), 
});
```

Router -

```
App.VideoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return App.Video.find();
   },
});
```

index.html -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="video">
  <div class='about'>
    {{#each model}}
      <embed 
        width="420" height="345" 
        src= "{{url}}" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      </embed>
    {{/each}}
 </div>
</script>
```

My JSON Response from server side -

```
{ 'id': '1', 'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/v/GnzZyGQi2ps' }
```

But if I am giving src like 'http://www.youtube.com/v/GnzZyGQi2ps' in above handlebars then its playing.

Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{unbound url}}` to avoid the script metamorph tags:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="video">
  <div class='about'>
    {{#each model}}
      <embed 
        width="420" height="345" 
        src="{{unbound url}}" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      </embed>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Hope it helps.